# Chinese remainder theorem (two digit number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find a two digit number that, when divided by $2,3,4,5$ gives remainder of $1,1,3,0$.

Can it be solved by chinese remainder theorem? How?

Comment: Observation: Division by $2$ is redundant

Comment: Without CRT you could consider that $a+5$  is divisible by $2,3,4,5$

Comment: @kingW3 can you show the solution thanks a lot

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you show the solution with using CRT?

Comment: -1 for not showing any work whatsoever and straight up asking for a solution twice

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is the number that gives $1,1,3,0$ when divided by $2,3,4,5$ then $a+5$ is divisible by $2,3,4,5$. Which means $a+5$ is divisible by $60$.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use chinese remainder theorem all m must be pair-wise relatively prime that is co-prime with each other  but now (2,4)=2 that is not coprimes so we co not use CRT 
Use onather methods